# in-app Screenshot and attach to email without saving into library

Tags: xcode, screenshot

I would like to know what code should i use if i want to make my app able to take a screenshot of the screen by pressing a UIbutton and immediately pop up and Mail compose and email out the screenshot without saving it into photo library?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to add two frameworks to your project - `QuartzCore` and `MessageUI` and then do `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and `#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>`.

Your button press code should be like,

```
- (void)buttonPress:(id)sender
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

    if ( [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] ) {
        MFMailComposeViewController * mailComposer = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        mailComposer.delegate = self;
        [mailComposer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"attachment.jpg"];

        /* Configure other settings */

        [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Deepak, I have something unclear. How can the xcode knows where is the path and name of the screenshot i want to attach to as I did not save it?

Comment: Ok. I made some assumptions here. I assumed you wanted to take the screenshot of the current screen of your app. So I did `[self.view.layer renderInContext:..];` where `self` is your view controller. I drew the view onto an image and then extracted the `NSData` object by using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` on the image to get the JPEG representation. I could then pass the `NSData` object to the method `addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:` where `fileName` is the one the receiver of the mail will see.

Comment: So you don't need to read from the filesystem to do this. If you've a different requirement let me know.

Comment: Hi Deepak, One more question. Last time you taught me the code about overlapping images, and now i want to post on Facebook and have the code below, how can i do it ??

Comment: CGRect subviewFrame4 = [self.stamps.superview convertRect:self.stamps.frame toView:self.imageall]; [self.imageall addSubview:self.stamps]; self.stamps.frame = subviewFrame4;
    
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageall.frame.size);
    [self.imageall.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    
    self.outputView.image = image;

 FBStreamDialog* dialog = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
 
    WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE??
 [dialog show];

Comment: I recommend you open a different question for that as it is a tangential topic. As such I've not tinkered much with Facebook APIs like many others on SO so I suggest a new question would be the right way to go. Thanks.