# How to take a screenshot of a view and email it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview

Can I make my app take a screenshot of the contents of a view and attach it to an email? How?

Comment: You can take a look at [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450303/in-app-screenshot-and-attach-to-email-without-saving-into-library/6450665#6450665).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can convert your view to an image, then you could create an email with it.

This code ([from here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/email/how-to-send-email-with-attachments-example-using-iphone-camera-to-email-a-photo.html)) will allow you to send an email with an attachment:

```
    - (void)emailImageWithImageData:(NSData *)data
    {
      MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
      picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

      // Set the subject of email
      [picker setSubject:@"Picture from my iPhone!"];

      // Add email addresses
      // Notice three sections: "to" "cc" and "bcc" 
      [picker setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"emailaddress1@domainName.com", @"emailaddress2@domainName.com", nil]];
      [picker setCcRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"emailaddress3@domainName.com"]];   
      [picker setBccRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"emailaddress4@domainName.com"]];

      //    Fill out the email body text
      NSString *emailBody = @"I just took this picture, check it out.";

      // This is not an HTML formatted email
      [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

      // Attach image data to the email
      // 'CameraImage.png' is the file name that will be attached to the email
      [picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"CameraImage"];

      // Show email view    
      [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
      //if you have a navigation controller: use that to present, else the user will not
      //be able to tap the send/cancel buttons
      //[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];


      // Release picker
      [picker release];
    }

    - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
     {
       // Called once the email is sent
       // Remove the email view controller  
       [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
     }
```

To convert your view graphical representation to an image, use the code ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically)):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.window.bounds.size);
[self.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

[self emailImageWithImageData:data];
```

Comment: I must agree, something about this answer is beautiful. It is right to the point, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

From [this site](http://iphone-dev-tips.alterplay.com/2009/11/attaching-image-of-uiview-to-email.html):

```
 // CREATING MAIL VIEW
 MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
 controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
 [controller setSubject:@"Check this route out"];
 [controller setMessageBody:@"Attaching a shot of covered route." isHTML:NO];

 // MAKING A SCREENSHOT
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_mapView.frame.size);
 [_mapView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
 UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

 // ATTACHING A SCREENSHOT
 NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenshot);
 [controller addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"route"]; 

 // SHOWING MAIL VIEW
 [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
 [controller release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can please check the below code may help you

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage* image = [GMSScreenshot screenshotOfMainScreen];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"Screenshot"];
```

Comment: its take a screenshot of current view and then we use it as a image.and use in mfmailcomposer.....

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial for this. You can find the source code on github of this as wwll.

[Take Screen-shot of Current View and Attach it to Mail](http://mobilitytalks.wordpress.com/2012/04/18/take-screen-shot-of-current-view-and-attach-it-to-mail/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This way**

Put this mail code inside an Action

```
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){


  MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
  picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
  [picker setSubject:@"Test Screen Shot From app"];
  [picker addAttachmentData: UIImagePNGRepresentation([self screenshot]) mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"CameraImage.png"];

  [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Here is the screenshot method

```
- (UIImage *) screenshot {
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

  [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

  UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  return image;
}
```

**Run and Go!**

N.B.Don't forget to Import header `#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>`