# taking ipad in app screenshot and emailing

Tags: ipad, screenshot

I want to take an in app screenshot and email it. I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450303/in-app-screenshot-and-attach-to-email-without-saving-into-library), but it doesnt work for my app since i'm using storyboard. Nothing happens when I press my UIButton. Do i have to make my own view controller for it and call that, or is there another way to call the mail view controller

edit:

ok i fixed it by setting up an email account on a test deivce. didn't know that the device needs to have an email account setup on it for the method to work. Another problem im having is dismissing the mailComposer viewController. It doesnt dissappear when i click send, or cancel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that you linked should work even if you are using storyboards. Have you linked your button to the action properly? Have you tried adding an `NSLog` statement to make sure the method is firing when the button is tapped? Even using storyboards, you can still present a modal view in code.

Your code does need to be updated to support retina displays though...change the first line to:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.window.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.window.bounds.size);
```

Comment: my method is firing, but it never gets to presenting the modal view controller. if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) returns false.

Comment: ok i fixed it by setting up an email account on a test deivce. didn't know that the device needs to have an email account setup on it for the method to work. Another problem im having is dismissing the mailComposer viewController. It doesnt dissappear when i click send, or cancel.

Comment: found out how to dismiss the mail compose view controller. had to implement the mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error method and did [self dismissModalViewController...] in that to dismiss the email.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Remember, just because you are using storyboards you aren't limited to them.  You can still override or enhance any of their functionality in code.